# Computing products of Two Taylor Expansions

Tags: series-expansion

I would like the Taylor Expansion of
    $$
\frac{\log(u-1) + 1}{u}
$$
about the point 
    $u=2.5$ 
in closed form.
The best I've gotten so far is Taylor expand 
    $\log(u-1) + 1$ and $1/u$
separately about 
    $u=2.5$ 
and then I get a product of two sums.
    $$
\frac{\log(u-1)+1}{u}
= \left(
- \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2/5)^{n+1}(u-5/2)^n
\right)
\left(
1 + \log(3/2) - 
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-2/3)^k \frac{(u-5/2)^k}{k}
\right) 
$$
Reassuringly, Mathematica Simplifies this to the equation given, so I know that up to this point I haven't made a mistake.

```
Simplify[-Sum[(-2/5)^(k + 1)*(u - 5/2)^k, {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]*
    (1+Log[3/2] - Sum[(-2/3)^k*(u - 5/2)^k/k, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}])]

Out[1]=(1+Log[-1+u])/u
```

But I would like Mathematica to give me a closed form for $a_k$, where
    $$
\frac{\log(u-1)+1}{u} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (u-5/2)^k
$$
and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Have you seen `SeriesCoefficient[]`?

Comment: Yeah, Mathematica thinks its really clever and reduces the product of two sums immediately to $\frac{1 + \log(-1 + u)}{u}$, so trying
`SeriesCoefficient` on the above product of series doesn't work.

Comment: I was thinking that since you're expanding at a different point, then you'd use `SeriesCoefficient[fun, {u, 5/2, n}]`...

Comment: Right, I think that's sufficient to get to the answer I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As noted, this is as simple as evaluating

```
SeriesCoefficient[(1 + Log[u - 1])/u, {u, 5/2, n}]
```